# Analyzing Market Concentration's effect on Profit

Tags: r, statistics, bayesian, stan, economics

I am having trouble running a regression in R.  I would like to determine the sensitivity of one variable on another using a linear model , in this case, Market Concentration (HHI) on Profits (mkt.profit). I am receiving the following error when trying to run my simulation in STAN:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Stan does not support NA (in x) in data
failed to preprocess the data; sampling not done
```

A little background on the data ... It is a very large set of financial data from many companies over many years (1963-2014). The variable HHI, called the Hirschmann Herfindahl Index, is a measure of market concentration and therefore *competition* within industries (SIC codes).  *Mkt.profit* is calculated by summing the revenue of all companies within a given industry. So the data is organized by year and by industry.  The goal is to determine how strong the influence of *HHI* is on industry revenue (*mkt.profit*)... Here is the code I am having trouble with :

```
> D <- subset(data.cc, 
  select=c("gvkey","fyear","conm","at","revt","seq","xopr","sic"))
> names(D) <- c("gvkey", "year", "company", "assets", "sales", "equity", 
  "expenses", "market")

> D[,mkt.sales:=sum(sales), by = .(market, year)]
> D[,mkt.share:=sales/mkt.sales]
> D[,HHI:=sum(mkt.share^2), by = .(market, year)]
> D[,mkt.profit:=sum(sales-expenses), by = .(market, year)]

> stan.code="
+   data {
+     int<lower=0> N;
+     vector[N] x;
+     vector[N] y;
+ }
+   parameters {
+     real beta0;
+     real beta1;
+     real <lower=0> sigma;
+ }
+   model {
+     beta1 ~ gamma(0,0);
+     y ~ normal(beta0 + beta1*x, sigma);
+ }"

> DD<-list(N=length(mkt.profit),y=mkt.profit,x=HHI)
> STANout <-stan(model_code=stan.code,data=DD,iter=10000,chains=3)
```

.. At which point I get the error shown at the beginning of this post.  I attempted to use a gamma prior since I presume the relationship is positive, that is, higher HHI's corresponding to higher levels of profit.  But I wasn't sure what to put as the arguments ... so, if anyone could explain that also, I would be grateful.

Comment: Stan does not deal well with missing values (represented as `NA`). You may have to drop any rows with missing values when creating your dataset.

Comment: I ran "complete.cases" and "na.omit", but still getting the same error.

Comment: As Marius already said, the comment is correct.  Stan does not support `NA` values.   You have the choice to either drop them as Marius suggested or impute them by building a model for them. There's a chapter in the manual on coding missing data models.

Answer (score 0):

The NA values were generated when the variables mkt.profit and HHI were calculated. This was because there were negative values in the data. Removing these negative values fixed the problem.

```
D <- D[D$sales>0,]
D <- D[D$expenses>0,]
D <- D[D$assets>0,]
```